# when we need to pass nullptr to an object^ or EventArgs ? and why to pass EventArgs::Empty to EventArgs^?

Tags: .net, methods, c++-cli, eventargs, nullptr

I have a method in my code, it's name is bindingSource_PositionChanged.
the definition of it is:

```
private: System::Void bindingSource_PositionChanged(**System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e**) 
{
    toolStripStatusLabel->Text = String::Format("Datensatz {0:N0} von {1:N0}", bindingSource->Position + 1, bindingSource->Count);
}
```

My questions:

1. I have in my program calling the function in this way:

   ```
   bindingSource_PositionChanged(nullptr, System::EventArgs::Empty);
   ```

   my Question 1: what makes pass `System::EventArgs::Empty` to the parameter `e` of this function? or to any `System::EventArgs^`. and what makes pass `nullptr` to the parameter sender here? or to any `System::Object^`  sender?
2. I have in my program calling the function in another way:

   ```
   bindingSource_PositionChanged(nullptr, nullptr);
   ```

   Question 2: what makes a `nullptr` to the parameter e of this function? or to any parameter of the type `System::EventArgs^?`

Comment: Is this C#? I haven't seen the ^ character in its syntax before. EDIT: Or `toolStipStatusLabel->Text`

Comment: This is C++/CLI. Not C#.

Comment: it is C++/ClI. but i think the question will the same in c#.
what the meaning to pass nullptr to variable system.EventArgs?
and what the meaning to pass it to variable System.Object.sender?
and what is the meaning to pass System.EventArgs.Empty to variable system.EventArgs?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

This will matter if and only if the event's subscriber(s) do something with those values and expect them to be non-null. Normally the `sender` is the object most "responsible" for the event (and indeed often, but not always, the object that the subscriber *subscribed to*). `EventArgs` by itself doesn't convey any interesting information, so it is entirely possible that the caller doesn't check it; but for more interesting events it would be common for the subscriber to access some information from the args - so if it was `null` this would often fail. `EventArgs::Empty` simply avoids the need to create a new but uninteresting `EventArgs` instance each time - since there is no information, all your events that use `EventArgs` might as well use the same instance.

You *can* send `null` for either `sender` or `args`; but don't be surprised if that stops some handlers from loving you. It would be *preferable* to send the logical sender and (in the presumed absence of anything more interesting), `EventArgs::Empty`.

Comment: but in this function i don't find any reason to pass nullptr or pass EventArgs::Empty to it? i see that the sender and the EventArgs are not important to do this function its job? is that right?
thanks once again

Comment: @joniklaoud the entire point of an event is to separate the invoker and the subscriber; the invoker cannot say things like "are not important" - for all you know, the handler wants to use (for example) a single common "click" handler, and use the `sender` to find out *what* was clicked, and thus what to do - a common practice if the UI is being built dynamically at runtime. And similarly for any other non-UI example.